# Using UsernamePasswordForm authentication with a custom AuthenticationProvider

Tags: security, authentication, symfony

I'm struggling with a custom authentication mechanism for Symfony2.

**What I want to do:**
I need a modified behaviour of the regular UsernamePasswordForm based authentication. The only modification required is, that the credentials aren't checked against the database, but some custom unix auth deamon. The users themselves are still located in the database.

**What I did:**
I played around will a full fledged custom authentication provider based on this [Symfony cookbook entry](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) and will most parts just extending the different UsernamePassword classes, but it didn't work out yet. I had especially some problems setting up the AuthenticationListener in the service configuration as the `UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener` has a lot of required parameters. Currently I'm not sure if it will work out at the end, cause I've got some issues with our database setup.

**What I need:**
Is there a simpler way to modified the default login form without the complete requirement of a full AuthenticationProvider? Imho it's a quite common issue to have some custom modifications in the default behaviour.

Would be happy about any ideas or hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: I finally managed to solve my issue thanks to [this blog post](http://blog.vandenbrand.org/2012/06/19/symfony2-authentication-provider-authenticate-against-webservice/) showing a solution. The basic idea is to **extend** the default form login authentication and "steal" its listener. This way you can reuse most of the existing code. The critical parts are the creation and configuration of an `AuthenticationProvider` and a `SecurityFactory`. And don't miss to use your own provider key instead of `form_login` in the `security.yml`.

In the blog post the author creates his own `UserProvider`, but it's working with just the default database one, too.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this myself but you should be able to insert your own AuthenticationProvider by setting a paramter:

```
   security.authentication.provider.dao.class:
   ..Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\MyDaoAuthenticationProvider
```

Your provider would extend the Dao and overide checkAuthentication.

Again, I have not actually done this and the security system is very touchy so it may or may not work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Reading your idea remindes me that I somewhere already saw a solution overriding the core classes this way. Dunno why I didn't investigate it any further.

I'll report back after the holidays if this worked out.

Comment: I just posted my own answer, cause I found a very helpfull blog post. It's sharing the same base with your idea and yours maybe shorter and working too... but this way I was on the safe side. :D